# why product details not displayed in mailtrap during payment?

Tags: php, laravel, mailtrap

I want to send the give of an order and also of product(annonce) to Mailtrap, I tried by order whose id = 1 as a test, when sending, everything works fine, just give them of product(annonce) not displayed in Mailtrap, on the other hand giving them an order is displayed well.
I don't know exactly where the problem is. and why the product(annonce) information is not showing.

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/mailable', function(){
    $order = App\Order::find(1);
    //dd($order);
    return new App\Mail\OrderPlaced($order);
});
```

**OrderAnnonce.php**

```
class OrderAnnonce extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'order_annonce';
    protected $fillable = ['order_id','annonce_id','quantity'];
}
```

**Order.php**

```
class Order extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'billing_email', 'billing_name', 'billing_address', 'billing_city',
        'billing_province', 'billing_postalcode', 'billing_phone', 'billing_name_on_card', 'billing_discount',
         'billing_discount_code', 'billing_subtotal', 'billing_tax', 'billing_total', 'payment_gateway', 
         'error',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function annonces()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Annonce')->withPivot('quantity');
    }
```

**placed.blade.php**

```
Thank you for your order.

**Order ID:** {{ $order->id }}

**Order Email:** {{ $order->billing_email }}

**Order Name:** {{ $order->billing_name }}

**Order Total:** ${{ round($order->billing_total / 100, 2) }}

**Items Ordered**

@foreach($order->annonces as $annonce)
Name: {{ $annonce->name }} <br>
Price: ${{ round($annonce->price / 100, 2)}} <br>
Quantity: {{ $annonce->pivot->quantity }} <br>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a pivot table between your `annonce` and `order` models.

From the documentation on [Many To Many Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many):"*To determine the table name of the relationship's intermediate table, Eloquent will join the two related model names in alphabetical order. However, you are free to override this convention. You may do so by passing a second argument to the belongsToMany method*"

In your models relations, add a second parameter 'annonces_order':

```
return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class, 'Annonces_order');
```

and

```
return $this->belongsToMany(Annonce::class, 'Annonces_order');
```

Or, rename your table `Annonces_order` to `annonce_order`.

---

Edit:

Since you're using an intermediate model you need to tell your relations to actually use that model. Add `->using(OrderAnnonce::class)` to both of your relations:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Annonce')->using(OrderAnnonce::class)->withPivot('quantity');
```

More on [Defining Custom Intermediate Table Models](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models)